# Update method not updating user object, no issue with params or form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through

I'm learning rails by building a forum website and have two primary models: Users and Topics. They have a many-to-many relationship using `has_many_through` by way of a third model, `subscribed_topic`.

In the user show I have the following `form_for`, to allow users to select topics via checkboxes. I am trying to use it to save the selected topics to the particular user.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %> 
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:topic_ids, 
Topic.all.sample(50).each, :id, :topic_name) %> 
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I have this update method in my users controller, called when the form is submitted.

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Success!"
  else
    flash[:warning] = "Failed!"
  end
end
```

These are my user params:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
  :name, :email, :password,
  :password_confirmation, topic_ids: [])
end
```

These are the respective schema for reference:

```
create_table "subscribed_topics", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "topic_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "topics", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "topic_name"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_topics_on_user_id"
end

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  t.string   "password_digest"
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
end
```

EDIT: I added `topic_ids: []` to my user params but the update is not going through.

The logs show:

```
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 (0.1ms)  begin transaction
Topic Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" WHERE "topics"."id" = 41 ORDER BY "topics"."created_at" DESC
Topic Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" INNER JOIN "subscribed_topics" ON "topics"."id" = "subscribed_topics".
"topic_id" WHERE "subscribed_topics"."user_id" = ? ORDER BY "topics"."created_at" DESC  [["user_id", 1]]
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "subscribed_topics" ("user_id", "topic_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 1], ["topic_id", 41], ["created_at", "2019-03-03 19:49:43.212973"], ["updated_at", "2019-03-03 19:49:43.212973"]]
User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER(?) AND ("users"."id" != ?) LIMIT ?  [["email", "user.email@gmail.com"], ["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]

(0.3ms)  rollback transaction
```

EDIT: user and topic model validations

The validations in user are:

```
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
```

The only validation in topic is:

```
validates :topic_name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}
```

EDIT: The specific validation error came from the user model

```
Validation failed: Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
```

I don't understand why passing this collection of topics would trigger the password validation and pass the name and email validations, but for that I will ask a new question.

Comment: Use bang method `@user.update!(user_params)` to see validation error explicitly in the log

Comment: Thanks @Vasilisa ! That helped me find the exact issue!

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your params missiong topic_ids you can add it like sample code below

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
  :name, :email, :password,
  :password_confirmation, topic_ids: [])
end
```

Edit:

I think your update controller is already correct, other alternative for user to choose topic you can use collection_select

```
 <%= f.collection_select :topic_ids, Topic.all.sample(50), :id, :topic_name, {}, { multiple: true } %>
```

Comment: Hm, that makes complete sense. However, the update still isn't going through for some reason. @widjajayd

Comment: I changed to collection_select to see if it made a difference, but the update still isn't going through. I posted the logs, any ideas?

Comment: bottom of the log, you see rollback transaction meaning your updated data cannot be saved, you can check your validation rule first and also table relations between user and topic

Comment: I added the validations for the two models to my post because I am not sure what I should be looking for. I don't see anything that would be restrictive. Am I missing a validation? I'm not sure I know what you mean by table relations; the association is has_many_through.